# Golang selenium can't get network log in performance log

Tags: python, google-chrome, go, selenium-webdriver

I have two test sites,

Website 1, I can get the network log normally, and I can see all the request information

Website two, I can't get the network log, but I'm sure it sent several requests, there are get and post, but I can only get some logs like Page.loadEventFired / Page.frameStoppedLoading

Can anyone help me?
By the way, there is nothing wrong with my setup.

I try to use js to execute, but I can get the url, but I can't get the requestsbody,